# Java ee web application with no servlets, how it's possible?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jakarta-ee, web

First of all i'm a newbie in java-ee. I'm working as a java developer and where i work, the company has a web application with java-ee on the frontside and cache(intersystem) at the backend.

Is it possible that the web application may not have any servlet class? I only can find httpservlet imports.

From my understanding, java-ee application always work with servlets with his get/post/init method's. Am i right?

Also,I really don't get the difference between servlets and jsp's.

For the moment, I know that the application is using maven,struts2,jsp,hibernate,taglib...

(Sorry for my english,I try my best)

Comment: You will find tons of books, tutorials, videos online. You will find the answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You are not right, but not totally wrong either. Java-ee application mostly works with servlet but there is also others mechanisms involve like Filter and Listener.

Filters are used to manage request and response before and after servlets are called. For example you could use one to always redirect to a login page if there is no session.

[Filter documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html)

Listeners are used for listening to events in a web container, like Session creation.

I don't really know Struts2 but with a little of research i found out that it works with a front filter who is interpreting request and dispatch them to your Action class.

[Some infos about Struts](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077772/enterprise-java/struts-2-0-in-action.html)

A lot of Framework/Apis use a similar system it's actually the design pattern [Front Controller](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/front_controller_pattern.htm), springMVC and Jersey for example both work with an unique front servlet

As for the difference between JSP and servlet, JSPs are just file that are compiled by the web server as servlet.

Comment: First of all, thx for all the info. After learning about jsp and servlets. I found that jsp can be an alternative for servlets. Am i wrong?

Comment: Jsp are actually servlet, your .jsp files are juste description file that are use to auto-compile servlet . So yes technically you could make a jsp-only project but you should have to write java code in your JSP files which is not recommended for maintainability.